# The Images are not displaying in MAUI app after vs upgrade

Tags: android, maui

MAUI solution is not building and showing the following errors:
[image]

I am able to build the solution after removing the below entries from AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round"
```

but images are not displaying in the MAUI App for me even the default image.
[image]

This might be happening due to the recent upgrade i did for VS. Currently its Version 17.9.0 Preview 2.0 and I don't see a option to downgrade also.

- .NET v8
- Android Emulator - pixel_5 api-34

Comment: I have verified many workarround that others have  suggested but its not helping me.

Comment: The error indicates that the pic appicon does not exist in the resource file folder. You can add another picture in the folder and add it to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Have you tried clearing bin and obj and restarting VS afterwards?

Comment: Getting same error after adding a new icon com.companyname.mauiapp8:mipmap/newappicon.png (same with/without png) @GuangyuBai-MSFT

Comment: i have deleted the bin and object and restarted the VS but no luck. Getting same error @FreakyAli

Comment: You can check if the build action property of the image is MauiImage. Then you can open the .csproj file to check the `<!-- Images -->` code.

Comment: I have these @GuangyuBai-MSFT

<!-- App Icon -->
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

<!-- Splash Screen -->
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

<!-- Images -->
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

Comment: Just trying to understand if the error is something specific to my system or anything to do with VS 17.9.0 Preview 2.0  or .NET 8 or with the Emulator. If thats the case i Can resinstall everything and try

Comment: The default MAUI Project (from the VS template) should work without me doing anything

Comment: It might be the project issue. You can use the new project instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating net7-android to net8-android I started getting the same error. After I updated the nuget packages Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility to version 8.0.6, after which the build went without errors.

Perhaps removing these packages and reinstalling them with version 8.0.3 will help too. Because on my other computer this same project builds normally with versions 8.0.3.

P.S. before this I cleaned out the bin and obj folders

Answer (score 1):

For me my images worked in web and windows but not android. I discovered I didnt have the correct file name case in my css for the image.